# Getting IPAddress with XcvData

Tags: c++, visual-c++, spool, print-spooler-api, tcpmon

I am needing to get the ip of the printer but am not having much success.
Already tried in various ways. Currently my code is like this:

```
void Spl::GetIpAddress(LPSTR printerName)
{
    HANDLE hPrinter;
    PBYTE wAddress = NULL;      
    DWORD size;
    DWORD status;
    LPSTR portName = GetProt(printerName);
    std::ostringstream strTemp;
    strTemp << portName;

    string temp = ",XcvPort " + strTemp.str();
    //temp = ,XcvPort 192.168.2.247

    LPSTR tempLPSTR((LPSTR)temp.c_str());

    if(OpenPrinter(tempLPSTR,&hPrinter,NULL))
    {
        if (XcvData(hPrinter, L"IPAddress", NULL, 0,wAddress,31, &size,&status))
        {


        }
    }

}
```

When he tries to call the XcvData function  she not enter the 'IF'. And my object "wAddress" remains empty.
Because I'm not getting?

OBS: This code is based on the msdn doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562761(v=vs.85).aspx

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the server name in the `OpenPrinter` call.  The printer name should look something like this:

```
"\\\\myServer\\,XvcPort myPort"
```

To confirm that is the problem, call `GetLastError` when `OpenPrinter` fails.